# How to modify raphael text?

Tags: javascript, text, svg, raphael

After instantiating Raphael text like so

```
var t = paper.text(50, 50, "Raphaël\nkicks\nbutt!");
```

how do I go about then modifying that text?

`t.text = "test";` did not work for me.

Answer (score 39):

You must use the [`.attr()`<sup>docs</sup>](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/reference.html#Element.attr) method to change the text of an existing text element

like this

```
t.attr('text','new text here');
```

Comment: What about setting and id for a text? is it possible

Comment: I know I am very late, but would it be possible what @ChiragTayal asked? I am struggling with the same problem at the moment.