# How to change Raphael text element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael, jquery-events

I created a text element:

```
var gcText = paper.text(textPosX, textPosY, "myText");
gcText.attr({"text-anchor":end});
gcText.node.id = "myObject";
```

After loading the page I use some JS jQuery commands for modifying some elements and I also want to update the text. I already found these posts:
[How to modify raphael text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172618/how-to-modify-raphael-text) and
[Changing text in RaphaelJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490092/changing-text-in-raphaeljs)
... and tried this:

```
$('#myObject').attr("text","new text");
```

But had no luck with it! These commands change the text attribute inside the svg-text element, but not the text I can see on the page. Now I found out that there is a tspan-element inside the generated SVG:

```
<text id="myObject" [...] text="new text"><tspan dy="3.5">myText</tspan></text>
```

I can only see the "myText" and not the text from the text-attribute ("new text").
How can a change this text through jQuery commands?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably attempt to reference the Raphael object itself, not using jQuery. jQuery is great for DOM manipulation, with elements such as DIV, A, P, etc.

Raphael's API is much better suited for manipulating SVG.

Here is a similar question with the appropriate answer to your question:

[How to modify raphael text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2172618/how-to-modify-raphael-text)

Edit: Sample Rewrite of code:

```
function renderText(myText) {
    var gcText = paper.text(textPosX, textPosY, myText).attr({"text-anchor":end});
    gcText.node.id = "myObject";
}
//onload
renderText("First text to appear");

// call it second time
renderText("Second text to appear");
```

It doesn't EXACTLY change the text inside the SVG, rather it rewrites it. But you get the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As you can see in my post I already saw this similar question. But the result was like I wrote: only the text attribute inside the text-tag was modified, but not the text I can see on page (the text inside the tspan-tag). Any other ideas?

Comment: You have to re-write the SVG TEXT object. Place var gtText... inside a function and call it again, only the second time with the updated text.

Comment: Hm, difficult, because I create several text elements in an initial routine and then want to update individually a specific text element with ID xy. Thanks anyway!!

But I'm still wondering about the tspan tag? What is the relation between the text attribute and the "innerText" of the SVG text element?